# Error: input file is incompatible with i386 output

Tags: assembly, x86, ld, i386

```
kk333@kk333-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ nasm -f elf64 2.asm

kk333@kk333-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ ld -m elf_i386 -s -o 2.asm 2.o

ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `2.o' is incompatible with i386 output
```

My computer is x86_64. So, if I compile by ld -m elf_x86_64 -s -o 2.asm 2.o, then chmod 700/+x 2.o - gives bash: ./2.o: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.

I am new to this, so please explain the errors, and tell me how to resolve them.

Comment: `elf64` and `elf_i386` are different, so you can't mix those. Also, why are you telling `ld` to _output_ to a `.asm` file? And you can't execute the `.o` file; that's the input to the linker that you generate your executable from.

Comment: helpful page for makefiles: check this out: ( http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/CSC231_Makefile_for_linking_ASM_and_C_Files )